# How to configure IntelliJ 9.0 with GWT?

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea

I'm trying to setup my GWT library. I found [this old video](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/training/demos/GWT.html) that shows there should be a section title "Google Web Kit" under Settings->IDE Settings.

Sadly, I can't find anywhere in the settings "Google Web Kit" or GWT, except under Inspections.

How do I point IntelliJ to my GWT installation?

BTW, I'm using IntelliJ 9.0.3 Ultimate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. File -> Project Structure -> Modules
2. You should see `GWT` under you main module name (expand it to see). If `GWT` is not there add it (by pressing +)
3. Fill in the `Path to GWT installation directory` in the right pane (when GWT selected).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. All the IntelliJ help text etc assumes that you have already installed the GWT plugin (Settings | Plugins). It's not there "out of the box" as some of the pages suggest. Until you do that, GWT won't appear in any of the menus or drop-downs.